# Is there any story link between Shaun of the Dead, Hot Fuzz, and The World's End?

Tags: the-worlds-end, hot-fuzz, shaun-of-the-dead

The "Blood and Ice Cream" series is a group of three movies that have very different themes in each, but at the same time, share many similarities.

For example:

- The Cornetto: In Shaun of the Dead, it was a Strawberry; in Hot Fuzz it was a Vanilla; and in World's End it was a Mint, all tying into the themes of each movie.
- Some actors: The main ones were Simon Pegg and Nick Frost, the Bill Nighy, followed then by some other actors like Martin Freeman (Yvonne's boyfriend in SotD, Nicholas' superior in Hot Fuzz, and "O-man" in World's End)
- The Pokie Machine. (If you pay attention, you can notice the same tune play at a certain point in each movie)
- The "Shortcut" joke.

So, my question is: Is there any link between these three movies, or are these just easter eggs to be discovered when watching?

Comment: All is explained in [the wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Flavours_Cornetto_trilogy).

Comment: Well, the main actors play different people in each one, so placing these stories in the same universe somehow is going to require a major stretch. ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The direct answer to the question is, "No".  There is no **story** link between the three movies.  There are just a few general "references" to the movies, as you pointed out in your question, along with a running gag involving garden fences.

The only other point not covered is the overall theme of the movies, which [director Edgar Wright said](http://www.thestar.com/entertainment/movies/2013/08/23/edgar_wright_crawling_toward_the_apocalypse_and_a_sweet_finish.html) was "the individuals in a collective [...] about growing up and [...] about the dangers of perpetual adolescence".

Comment: The word is "Thematic".